# Flipping the top and bottom row of an array in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm stuck on a hw problem I have, asking me to take the values of the top row of an array in excel and flipping them with the bottom row's values, while the middle remains unchanged. I'm supposed to only change one line of code in VBA to accomplish this. Here is the code I have:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Function flip(DataRange As Range)
Dim nRows As Integer, nCols As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim A()
nRows = DataRange.Rows.Count
nCols = DataRange.Columns.Count
ReDim A(nRows, nCols)
For i = 1 To nRows
    For j = 1 To nCols
        A(i, j) = DataRange.Cells(***<replace with formula>***, j) 
    Next j
Next i
flip = A
End Function
```

The array in Excel goes as follows:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

*both arrays are 3x3

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I can only change the ***replace with formula*** input of DataArray.Cells( , j)

Answer (score 1):

Just a little math and use the number of rows. I would go with Long rather than Integer and ideally be explicit with sheet references.

```
Option Base 1

Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, arr()

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.[A1].CurrentRegion

    arr = flip(rng)

    Activesheet.[A7].Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
End Sub

Public Function flip(DataRange As Range)
    Dim nRows As Integer, nCols As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim A()
    nRows = DataRange.Rows.Count
    nCols = DataRange.Columns.Count
    ReDim A(nRows, nCols)
    For i = 1 To nRows
        For j = 1 To nCols
            A(i, j) = DataRange.Cells(nRows - i + 1, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    flip = A
End Function
```